# Dynamically allocated unknown length string reading from file (it has to be protected from reading numbers from the file) in C

Tags: c, string, file, pointers, dynamic-memory-allocation

My problem is such that I need to read string from file. File example:

> Example 1 sentence
>
> Example sentence number xd 595 xd 49 lol

but I have to read only the string part, not numbers. I guess I have to use `fscanf()` with `%s` for it but let me know what you guys think about it.
The part where my problem begins is how to read the string (it is unknown length) using `malloc()`, `realloc()`? I tried it by myself, but I failed (my solution is at bottom of my post).
Then I need to show the result on the screen.

P.S. I have to use `malloc()/calloc()`, `realloc()` <-- it has to be dynamically allocated string :) (`char *`)

Code I've tried:

```
    int wordSize = 2;
    char *word = (char *)malloc(wordSize*sizeof(char));
    char ch;

    FILE* InputWords = NULL;
    InputWords = fopen(ListOfWords,"r"); /* variable ListOfWords contains name of the file */

    if (InputWords == NULL)
    {
      printf("Error while opening the file.\n");
      return 0;
    }

    int index = 0;
    while((ch = fgetc(InputWords)) != -1)
    {
      if(ch == ' ')
      {
        printf("%s\n", word);
        wordSize = 2;
        index = 0;
        free(word);
        char* word = (char *)malloc(wordSize*sizeof(char));
      }
      else
      {
        wordSize++;
        word = (char *)realloc(word, wordSize*sizeof(char));
        strcpy(word,ch);
        index++;
      }
    }
  fclose(InputWords);
```

Comment: unrelated suggestion: use `EOF` (may be any negative value) instead of `-1`

Comment: `char ch:` ==> `int ch;`

Answer (score 1):

For your code, you have something have to improve:

1. `fgetc` return the `int` type not `char`. So change `char ch` to `int ch`;
2. As the comment of @pmg use EOF (may be any negative value) instead of -1`
3. `strcpy(word,ch);` you try to copy character (`ch`) to character pointer (`word`).
4. Do not cast `malloc` or `realloc` function: [Do I cast the result of malloc?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc).

For solving your question, i propose you use the `strtok` function to split string by space character, then test each word is number or not. If the word is not a number, you can use `strcat` to concatenate the word to the old sentence.

The complete code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int is_number(char *str) {
    if (strlen(str) == 0)
       return -1;
    for(int i =0; (i < strlen(str)) && (str[i] != '\n') ; i++) {
        if(!isdigit(str[i]))
            return -1;
    }
    return 1;
}

int main()
{
    FILE *fp = fopen("input.txt", "r");
    char line[256];

    if(!fp) return -1;
    char **sentence;
    int i = 0;
    sentence = malloc(sizeof(char *));
    if(!sentence) return -1;
    while(fgets(line, 256, fp)) {
        char * token = strtok(line, " ");
        size_t len = 0;
        sentence = realloc(sentence, sizeof(char *) * (i+1));
        if(!sentence) return -1;
        while(token != NULL) {
            if (is_number(token) != 1) {

                sentence[i] = realloc(sentence[i], len + 2 + strlen(token)); // +2 because 1 for null character and 1 for space character
                if (!sentence[i]) {
                    printf("cannot realloc\n");
                    return -1;
                }
                strcat(strcat(sentence[i], " "), token);
                len = strlen(sentence[i]);
            }
            token = strtok(NULL, " ");
        }
        if(len > 0)
           i++;
    }

    for(int j = 0; j < i; j++) {
        printf("line[%d]: %s", j, sentence[j]);
    }

    for(int j = 0; j < i; j++) {
        free(sentence[j]);
    }
    free(sentence);
    fclose(fp);
    return 0;
}
```

The input and output:

```
$cat input.txt
Example 1 sentence
Example sentence number xd 595 xd 49 lol

./test

line[0]:  Example sentence                                                                                                                                  
line[1]:  Example sentence number xd xd lol
```

Comment: I will test it evening and give you feedback. Anyway your solution seems legit

Comment: @Cris as you see in my answer, i have tested it with your input. The output in my answer is what you want ?

Comment: "cannot realloc" appears all the time. Any ideas why it goes like that?

Comment: @Cris did you copy and paste correctly my code ? It works by using online compiler https://onlinegdb.com/HkXzR38jI

Comment: it works also on my PC. Try to copy and paste the code.

Comment: I pasted it, but changed some variable names. I will try copy 1:1

Comment: I copied it 1:1 but there still is a problem. It works once per 5 times. Could we go any live chat? Of course if you have some time and want to help me

Comment: if you want, i'm free now

Comment: How can I contact with you?

Comment: because you lack of reputation, so, you cannot access to chat room of stack overflow

Comment: I know, that's why i ask :v facebook maybe?